# My Firebase Authentication Dependency Issue

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I added this line of code to my android Manifest in trying to add the Firebase Authentication Dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is what the error I keep seeing when I sync the Gradle:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'ng.org.fafic.fafic'
```

How do I resolve this error, please?

---

Now, when I leave my gradle to be like this:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
}
```

My project will compile without any error. It will even allow me to use the Firebase classes for authentication. But when I try to run the app, the app crashes and I am left with this error:

```
Process: ng.org.fafic.fafic, PID: 24478


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ng.org.fafic.fafic/ng.org.fafic.fafic.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at ng.org.fafic.fafic.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:35)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2752)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: check, you added
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  at the bottom of the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

```
> No matching client found for package name 'ng.org.fafic.fafic'
```

This error happens when the `google-services.json` is missing in your build.
Also check if the `package_name` in the `google-services.json` has a correct value according to your package name.

```
{
  "project_info": {

  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I did copy the google-services.json into my src folder. and I have verified and the package name is contained in that file

Comment: @Bright the google-services.json file should be placed in the module folder, not inside the src folder.

Comment: Well, now I am officially confused as I have been searching for the module folder since reading your reply. Kind Sir, how do I locate this module folder?

Comment: Usually it is the app folder

Comment: If its the Folder above the src folder, then I tried placing it there but getting this kind of error that gradle is looking for the service in a specific location which is why I placed it at the src folder

Comment: Also, I failed to include this line of code: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' and the project synced. I don't know what's wrong with this process...

Comment: Did you remove the plugin line?

Answer (score 0):

As i've seen from your replies with @Gabriele, Please check with me as the following.

First, Check if you've already downloaded the SDK for using Google Play Services/Firebase .

After checking, you need to add Google play services lib in your build.gradle app's level, and the firstbase, for me i used the messaging one too :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
```

And in the last line ( out of all brackets {} ), you need to add this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now, in your build.gradle Project's level, you need to add this inside 'dependencies' brackets

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

the most important piece is your json file, download the json file and navigate to your project/your-app folder and paste it there, your app folder is the folder that contain files/folders like src/libs/build etc ..